# How do i grant permission on my Luis.ai application to other microsoft account?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I own a Luis.ai application which I use for my chat BOT.
i want my qa guys to be able to train my Luis.ai application, so that my BOT would be smarter.
how do i grant permissions to other user to train my APP?

Answer (score 2):

Now there is an option to set other users as "Collaborator" and they can then Train and modify the luis.ai app as needed.
The accounts can be independent and don't need to be from same Azure Active Directory or otherwise linked.
[Basic description by Microsoft is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-collaborate)

This way you add the Collaborator at

https://www.luis.ai/applications/yourAppId/0.1/settings

[image: This way you add the Collaborator]

And this way the collaborator sees the UI:

[image: This way the collaborator sees the UI]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's currently possible.

The easiest workaround I can think of is to create a shared account, export your LUIS application from your account and import it into the new shared account. Have in mind that the keys of your LUIS app will likely change and so you will likely need to update your bot too.

Also, you can see if using the [Cognitive Services API](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c45) is suitable for your scenario. If it's, then there are a bunch of operations available there.

Comment: Was this useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cognitive Services API for this.

Link - https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c45

I haven't actually used it but you can have a look. Hope this helps.